# form fields not aligning properly when using CSS table

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML (also in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3145f60/14/)) I am using CSS tables to align the fields in the form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     form {
       display: table;
       width: 200px;
     }
     form>div {
       display: table-row;
     }
     form>div>label {
       display: table-cell;
       padding-right: 10px;
       text-align: right;
       vertical-align: middle;
     }
     form>div>input, form>div>textarea {
       display: table-cell;
       }     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for='form-name'>Name:</label>
        <input id='form-name' type='text'/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for='form-email'>Email:</label>
        <input id='form-email' type='email'/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for='form-comments'>Comments:</label>
        <textarea id='form-comments'></textarea>
      </div>            
      <div>
        <input type='submit'/>
        <input type='reset'/>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My questions are:

1. why does the textarea cell have a greater width than that of the cells above it?
2. why don't the two button input fields reside on the same row?

## update

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3145f60/15/) based on the accepted answer.

Comment: have you ever considered putting the elements in a html table to keep them aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `width: 100%;` to `form>div>input, form>div>textarea` and following css:

```
input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
}
```

will make it as per your expected output.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3145f60/11/)**

Comment: `display: inline-block` does not seem to be necessary. Also I have to set the width of `form>div>textarea` to 99% otherwise it's a bit off to the right. I've updated my question with the jsfiddle that works for me. I am accepting this answer even though it is opaque to me why this works.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I've explained how and why textarea width doesn't work well, check it out, it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. all 4 `div` have the same width in your fiddle.
2. use float's on the submit and reset input's to display them on the same row

Answer (score 0):

Attached a snippet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    form {
      display: table;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    form>div {
      display: table-row;
    }
    
    form>div>label {
      display: table-cell;
      padding-right: 10px;
      text-align: right;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    form>div>div {
      display: table-cell;
    }
    
    form>div>div>input {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    form>div>div>textarea {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    form
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label forName='form-name'>Name:</label>
      <div>
        <input id='form-name' type='text' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label forName='form-email'>Email:</label>
      <div>
        <input id='form-email' type='email' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label forName='form-comments'>Comments:</label>
      <div>
        <textarea id='form-comments'></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='submit' />
      <input type='reset' />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <form>         
        <tr>
            <td><label for='form-name'>Name:</label><br>
            <input id='form-name' type='text'/></td>
        </tr>            
        <tr>
            <td><label for='form-email'>Email:</label><br>
            <input id='form-email' type='email'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for='form-comments'>Comments:</label><br>
            <textarea id='form-comments'></textarea></td>
        </tr>            
        <tr>
            <td><input type='submit'/>
            <br>
         <input type='reset'/></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
  display: table;
  width: 200px;
}
form div {
  display: table-row;
}
form div label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
form div input, form div textarea {
  display: table-cell;
} 

div{
   border:1px solid black;
}

table td input, table td textarea{
   width: 100%;
}

table td{
   width: 150px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/n3145f60/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

First a comment about label for:

label `forName="form-email`

should be written:

label `for="form-email`

This is quite useful for:

label (text) click -> focus on input field that text is used for.

To answer your questions:

1. why does the textarea cell have a greater width than that of the cells above it?

It happens because of html element textarea can have rows and cols attributes inside, it has default values if you don't specify it. Check this for example (it would be 50% less in size):

```
<textarea cols="10" rows="5" id='form-comments'></textarea>
```

Default values are listed here (20 cols, 2 rows):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_rows.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_cols.asp

If you would like to override it just put width: 100% to fill width.

2. Why don't the two button input fields reside on the same row?

You're using table displays on divs and your styles aren't specific enough, you're making general div and input styles and that's your problem.
To fix this, omit last div that wraps your buttons so you just have:

```
<input type='submit'/>
<input type='reset'/>
```

And remove display: table from your "form" styles.

https://jsfiddle.net/n3145f60/13/